# Ignoring <Button-1> when <Key> is pressed Tkinter, Python

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter, visualization

I want to swop tiles on my board (in game fifteen) by the inputted keys. It works perfectly for up/down/right/left, but not for the digit keys 1...9, even though their coordinates get updated correctly within my play() function, it still doesn't seem to move on the board. My full code is: http://pastebin.com/KvL2JF1G Any tips??

This is my key event:

```
def key(event):
    if event.char.isdigit():
        for j, row in enumerate(board):
            for i, char in enumerate(row):
                if char.get() == event.char:
                    print "pressed", repr(event.char),i, j
                    play(i,j)
```

Now the main part is in play() which changes the string_vars in each label that swops with the empty label (blankx,y are the coordinates for the empty space):

```
def play(i,j):
    global blankx, blanky, game_running
    if game_running:
        # update vars if tile can be moved
        if (blankx, blanky) in [(i+1,j),(i-1,j),(i,j+1),(i,j-1)]:
            board[blanky][blankx].set(board[j][i].get())
            board[j][i].set(' ')

            blanky = j
            blankx = i
```

This is for all visualization and events:

```
for j, row in enumerate(board):
    for i, string_var in enumerate(row):
        b = Label(frame, textvariable=string_var, bg='pink', width=2, height=1, font=("Times", 30, 'bold'), relief=RAISED)  
        b.grid(row=j, column=i, sticky="nsew", ipadx=8, padx=4, pady=4)
        b.bind('<Button-1>',lambda e, i=i,j=j:play(i,j))
        b.bind('<Key>', key)
        b.bind('<Right>', right_Key)
        # ... same function for left/up/down
        b.focus_set()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `key()` you have to stop checking board when you made move.

Now `key()` moves tile to new place and then it is still searching and it finds the same tile in new place and it moves it to old place.

BTW: seen text printed in console - you see `"pressed"` twice.

You need `return` to stop searching.

```
def key(event):
    print(event.widget)
    if event.char.isdigit():
        for j, row in enumerate(board):
            for i, char in enumerate(row):
                if char.get() == event.char:
                    print "pressed", repr(event.char),i, j, blankx,blanky
                    play(i,j)
                    return # stop searching
```

Comment: That works! Thanks! So <Button-1> only picks up the clicks and ignores the key input right? Similarly, if I put in <right> then <key> event won't pick it up? Also, any ideas on how I can input double digits as keys, say move tile 13?

Comment: `<Button-1>` means only `left mouse button`. (`<Button-3>` = `right mouse button`). `<key>` catch all keyboard keys (maybe except `Ctrl`, `Shift`, but I'm not sure) - it should catch `<right>` too. Probably you don't have to bind `<key>` and `<right>` to all labels - you can bind it only once to `root`. But `<Button-1>` have to be bind to `Label`. Maybe use letters instead numbers ?

Comment: Yes, I'm binding them to root now, and it seems also fine! The way I saw this in Tkinter was that: I have an initial window (root), then I created a frame on this in which I have my labels. If I want anything to happen to those labels, I need to refer back to them. But I guess, since label is on frame, frame is on root, root still captures the key events.. Any idea on any other ways of inputting double digit numbers?

Comment: theoretically you can recognize by  "1<wait_short_time>3" (13) and "1<wait_short_time><nothing>" (1) but there is no special method for this. probably you will have to keep keys on the list and call another function after "short time" to check if you have two keys on the list.